# Python: How can I access IDs separated by | (pipe) in an argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, python-2.x, flags

I have searched both here and using google. The | (pipe) symbol is the bitwise OR operator, but I can't find anything specific to my problem. Here is an [example](https://developers.maxon.net/docs/Cinema4DPythonSDK/html/modules/c4d.gui/GeDialog/index.html#GeDialog.AddButton) from the Cinema4D Python SDK and has an argument *flags* where you can set multiple IDs separated by the | symbol.

What is this specifically and how do I access the IDs in the function below?

```
ID_OK = 100
ID_CANCEL = 101

def Func(flags):
    print flags
    return

Func(ID_OK|ID_CANCEL)

..

>> 101
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags like this are sometimes called "bit-masks".  If you define them as hexadecimal you will find them much easier to use.

You can use binary `&` to determine if the flag is set.  For example:

```
ID_OK = 0x01
ID_CANCEL = 0x10

def Func(flags):
    print "0x%02x" % (flags)
    if flags & ID_OK:
        print "ID_OK"
    if flags & ID_CANCEL:
        print "ID_CANCEL"

    print
    return

Func(ID_OK)
Func(ID_CANCEL)
Func(ID_OK|ID_CANCEL)
```

Gives:

```
0x01
ID_OK

0x10
ID_CANCEL

0x11
ID_OK
ID_CANCEL
```

Flags are usually larger than this.  If you have a small number of flags then it is much simpler if you can reserve one nybble for each flag.

Comment: Thank you and DeepSpace, took a while but I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to "space out" the values of the flags in such a way that each combination of `|` with arbitrary number of flags produces a unique value. That way you can tell each flags are meant to be used simply by the value of the argument.

Even though the following article talks about C# you can still get the idea:
http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/